# PHP unset returns my json array with int indexes

Tags: php, json, unset

i have a problem with my json index remover , so far i tryed this

```
$cars = json_decode($json_user , true);
foreach ($cars as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array('BH', $value)) {
        unset($cars[$key]);
    }
}
echo $cars = json_encode($cars);
```

With the JSON content

```
[{"code":"AB"},{"code":"BC"},{"code":"CD"}]
```

When using the script above to remove the index containing BC it returns me this

```
{"0":{"code":"AB"},"2":{"code":"CD"}}
```

instead of this

```
[{"code":"AB"},{"code":"CD"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as expected. The PHP arrays are association maps. Removing a key doesn't affect the other keys of the array.

Use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reindex `$cars` before encoding it as JSON.

Answer (score 3):

The JSON format is based in JavaScript syntax and JavaScript arrays cannot have sparse keys. Try dropping current keys and reindexing the array:

```
echo $cars = json_encode(array_values($cars));
```